# Iterate through all files in a directory and find and replace text - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, glob

Baby brand new. This was Frankenstein'ed together from a few similar topics, none of which seemed to cover the necessary step of nesting a find and replace inside a file loop.

I am attempting to iterate through every file in a folder (not recursively, I only have one folder level) of a specific type (listed here as a '.LIC') and replace a short bit of text. The following is as close as I could come:

```
import glob, os, fileinput
from glob import glob
root_dir = r"myPath"
os.chdir(root_dir)
    for file in glob, glob('*.LIC'):
    filename = str(file)
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace('findText', 'replaceText'),  end='')
```

As you can imagine this went swimmingly. The error code is placed below.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-e2fd0e9a5df9> in <module>()
      6     filename = str(file)
      7     with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
----> 8         for line in file:
      9             print(line.replace('findText', 'replaceText'), end='')
     10 

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\fileinput.py in __next__(self)
    246     def __next__(self):
    247         while True:
--> 248             line = self._readline()
    249             if line:
    250                 self._filelineno += 1

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\fileinput.py in _readline(self)
    333                     pass
    334                 # The next few lines may raise OSError
--> 335                 os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
    336                 self._file = open(self._backupfilename, self._mode)
    337                 try:

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<function glob at 0x00000000013D3400>' -> '<function glob at 0x00000000013D3400>.bak'
```

I think my problem is nesting a reference to 'file', but I am unsure how to resolve this.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Frankenstein'ed together - ha ha ha :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop over the result of `glob` and not a tuple with the function object `glob`:

```
for filename in glob('*.LIC'):
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace('findText', 'replaceText'),  end='')
```